# Get human readable Windows WiFi adapter name

Tags: c#, windows, wifi

The following code lists all WiFi adapters (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.findalladaptersasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-devices-wifi-wifiadapter-findalladaptersasync):

```
var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
foreach (var adapter in result)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Adapter: " + adapter.Id + ", " + adapter.Name + ", " + adapter.ToString());
}
```

But the `adapter.Id` is some cryptic string and `adapter.Name` returns the Windows machine name. Is there a way to get a human readable representation of the WiFi adapter name?

Regards,

Comment: The simplest wait is to use WlanEnumInterfaces (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanenuminterfaces)

Comment: Can you point me to the part where a human readable name is produced? The linked example also seems to return only GUIDs.

Comment: The example returns the WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST structure that contains array of the WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO structures each one has strInterfaceDescription field. That is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Adapter: " + adapter.Id + ", " + adapter.Name + ", " + adapter.ToString());
```

**Please Try Console.Writeline();?**